# jquery: turning multiple functions into one plugin

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-plugins

I am learning to turn a function into a plugin. and turning a function into a plugin seems quite straight forward. But what if I have two functions correspond with each other - how can I turn these two functions into one plugin then?

such as I have these functions for making a jquery slideshow,

```
function run_slide(target_slide) {

    //add a class the the first element
    $('li:first-child',target_slide).addClass('active');

    //Set the opacity of all images to 0
    $('.slide li').css({opacity: 0.0});

    //Call the gallery function to run the slideshow, 6000 = change to next image after 6 seconds
    setInterval('loop_slide("'+target_slide+'")',5000);
}

function loop_slide(target_slide) {

    //Get next image, if it reached the end of the slideshow, rotate it back to the first image
    var next = ((current.next().length) ? ((current.next().hasClass('caption'))? $('.slide li:first-child') :current.next()) : $('.slide li:first-child')); 

    //Set the fade in effect for the next image, show class has higher z-index
    current.addClass('last-active');
    next.css({opacity: 0.0})
    .addClass('active')
    .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function(){
        current.animate({opacity: 0.0}, 1000).removeClass('active last-active');

        $('.caption p',target_slide).html(caption_description);
    });

}
```

this is how I call these functions,

```
run_slide('#slide');
```

ideally I would like to call these functions from the plugin method,

```
$('#slide').run_slide();
```

but how to wrap these two functions into the plugin making method below as in [jquery's documenation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring),

```
(function( $ ){
  $.fn.myPlugin = function() {

    // Do your awesome plugin stuff here

  };
})( jQuery );
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $.fn.run_slide = function {
        var target_slide = $(this);
        //add a class the the first element
        $('li:first-child', target_slide).addClass('active');

        //Set the opacity of all images to 0
        $('.slide li').css({
            opacity: 0.0
        });

        //Call the gallery function to run the slideshow, 6000 = change to next image after 6 seconds
        setInterval(function() {
            target_slide.loop_slide();
        }, 5000);
    }

    $.fn.loop_slide = function() {
        var target_slide = $(this);
        //Get next image, if it reached the end of the slideshow, rotate it back to the first image
        var next = ((current.next().length) ? ((current.next().hasClass('caption')) ? $('.slide li:first-child') : current.next()) : $('.slide li:first-child'));

        //Set the fade in effect for the next image, show class has higher z-index
        current.addClass('last-active');
        next.css({
            opacity: 0.0
        }).addClass('active').animate({
            opacity: 1.0
        }, 1000, function() {
            current.animate({
                opacity: 0.0
            }, 1000).removeClass('active last-active');

            $('.caption p', target_slide).html(caption_description);
        });
    }
});
```

or you could also define another function inside the plugin like this:

```
$.fn.run_slide = function(){
    function loop_slide(){
        //...
    }

    loop_slide.call(this);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

According to jquery's docs/style guide a single plugin should not clutter up the $.fn namespace with multiple entries. But your single plugin requires multiple functions, as you've drawn it up. The answer is a singleton like so: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Namespacing The first code block is what you should not do. The second is what you should do. You create a singleton with all your methods attached. Via scope closure that singleton is available to your plugin $.fn... call. This way your plugin can work on multiple DOM objects at the same time while not cluttering up the jquery namespace, or memory-space with multiple instances of your functions running around. All around win :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this [creating a jquery plugin with multiple functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096451/creating-a-jquery-plugin-with-multiple-functions)