# Multiple methods on a plugin callback

Tags: jquery, jquery-callback

Is there a way to add multiple methods on a plugin callback? e.g. suppose there is this plugin that allow calling a method via "afterInit" callback

```
$("div.block-20").myPlugin({
    afterInit : method1
});
```

Now i want to run another method (method2) too. Anyway to do that without tweak plugin or merging 2 methods (method1, method2)?

Comment: This answer is right for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4096550/6166191

Answer (score 1):

You can use an anonymous function as callback function:

```
$("div.block-20").myPlugin({
    afterInit : function() {
        method1();
        method2();
        // do something other
    }
});
```